# Sending Robocopy log as email attachment

Tags: file, logging, robocopy

How to send robocopy log file as email attachment,As using below command to copy the files and save the log file and it works fine.

@echo off

robocopy C:\Narsing\XX\Robocopy\Source\ C:\Narsing\XX\Robocopy\Destination /E /Log:C:\Narsing\GE\Robocopy\Test.log

Please help me to send these log as an email attachment

Can any one help me here

Answer (score -1):

You can try BLAT 3.23

http://sourceforge.net/projects/blat/files/Blat%20Full%20Version/64%20bit%20versions/

Ex. file script

---

```
@ECHO OFF

ECHO Benachrichtigungsmail wird versandt

ECHO.

rem Email to a1@ddd.de 
c:\blat.exe c:\hotbackup.log -server mail.domain.net -to a1@ddd.de-f a1@ddd.de -s BD-Backup

rem Email to a2@ddd.de
c:\blat.exe c:\hotbackup.log -server 10.1.2.1 -to a2@ddd.de -f 2a@ddd.de -s BD-Backup

ECHO.

EXIT
```